# compress a whole folder on remote ftp server with php

Tags: php, ftp, zip

I've been trying to come up with a way to build an automated PHP transfer system between 2 servers. Server A : only ftp access; server B : ftp access and can run php scripts.

I want to copy all file in server A to a folder in server B;

Here is what I am trying to do :

1: function compress_each_ftp_folder_or_file_in_ftp_Backups_folder();

2: function delete each_ftp_folder_in_ftp_Backups_folder_after_successful_zipping();

3: function download_each_archive_in_ftp_Backups_folder();

4: function delete_each_archive_after_successful_download();

I have some scripts for step 2, 3 and 4 but nothing found on web that help me with step 1;
I found lot of codes to compress folders or files on local server, but I don't found any script that compress a whole folder on a remote ftp server.

I think it was the time to ask for a help. Thanks for helping me.

Answer (score 0):

FTP protocol won't let you perform compression on the remote server so there's no direct way to accomplish the task.

In some cases some servers let you execute shell commands using SITE command. If you are lucky enough and this is supported on your server then you can call remote compression tool (zip would do) using SITE command with zip command invocation as a parameter. IF this is not supported by your server, then you need to use non-technical measures (eg. contact server admins for assistance).

Comment: Thanks for your reply; I will ask my server admin to know if I could execute SITE command on their server. Have a nice day;